# How to make table header fixed in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, webview

I want to show a table in android webview,it reqest the table can sroll both horizontal and vertically.

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    background: #fff;
}

td, th {
    padding: 0.75em 1.5em;
    text-align: left;
}

    td.err {
        background-color: #e992b9;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 0.75em;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 1;
    }

th {
    background-color: #31bc86;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.thead {
    position: fixed;
}

tbody th {
    background-color: #2ea879;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(2n-1) {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    transition: all .125s ease-in-out;
}

tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: rgba(129,208,177,.3);
}
```

```html
<table >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>产品ID</th>
                <th>产品编码</th>
                <th>产品名称</th>
                <th>产品规格</th>
                <th>配置</th>
                <th>配置1</th>
                <th>配置2</th>
                <th>单价</th>
                <th>折扣</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A86</td>
                <td>产品1</td>
                <td>10X10</td>
                <td>sfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</td>
                <td>333333333333333</td>
                <td>1923</td>
                <td>0.9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I try to use [StickyTableHeaders][1]

[1]: https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders ,and it works in my windows chrome,but it does not work in Android when call webView.loadUrl,it seems that the js does not work in android,the logcat show "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'stickyTableHeaders'.Can anyone help me solve this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript not enabled by default. You have to enable it by:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```